# Highlighting cell if row has missing entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to work out how to highlight a cell when a row has missing entries via a formula or conditional formatting. For example, let's take row 2 in a table. Table entries go up to column N. I want to find a way to highlight A2 if there are any missing entries in B2, C2,...,N2.

Answer (score 2):

Use below formula in Conditional formatting

```
=COUNTBLANK(B2:N2)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a flag to column M with the following formula:

```
={ISBLANK($B2:$N2)}
```

Note: Don't type the {}'s hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just Enter

Select the whole table (asssuming you start in row 2) then apply conditional formatting like so:

Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...

With the formula being

```
=$M2
```

Set the formatting as you wish